# Swift iOS application crashed when I hit on a button that need to take me other viewcontroller

Tags: swift

I am developing a Swift iOS application, when I tried to hit on login button it needs to pull the user information from the MySQL database and have to verify with user provided values. I am doing all this stuff fine. After verifying credential I need to navigate to the other view controller, but unfortunately my app getting crashed at this point and given the below error.

```
2015-09-29 18:15:43.839 iOSBudgetManager[2998:66920] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374
2015-09-29 18:15:43.867 iOSBudgetManager[2998:66920] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e67cc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110429bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e67caca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010ed5b98f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010f8b57d6 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 151
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010f356912 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 473
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010f6014ad -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1002
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010f609834 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 504
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010f2994f1 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 623
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f29a76e -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3079
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010f29c6c1 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010f29c5e5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    12  iOSBudgetManager                    0x000000010df507c0 _TFFC16iOSBudgetManager14ViewController13WelcomesigninFS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_U_FTGSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo7NSError__T_ + 6752
    13  iOSBudgetManager                    0x000000010df50c03 _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFo_iTGSQS__GSQS0__GSQS1____iT__ + 51
    14  iOSBudgetManager                    0x000000010df4c131 _TPA__TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFo_iTGSQS__GSQS0__GSQS1____iT__ + 81
    15  iOSBudgetManager                    0x000000010df50c33 _TTRXFo_iTGSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo7NSError___iT__XFo_oGSQS__oGSQS0__oGSQS1___dT__ + 35
    16  iOSBudgetManager                    0x000000010df50c9a _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFdCb_dGSQS__dGSQS0__dGSQS1___dT__ + 90
    17  CFNetwork                           0x00000001117d8beb __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 157
    18  Foundation                          0x000000010ed7f57f __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    19  Foundation                          0x000000010ecc00b2 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
    20  Foundation                          0x000000010eca2774 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
    21  Foundation                          0x000000010eca2383 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110b2b614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110b126a7 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2176
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110b11cc0 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110b153b9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1359
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110b16b17 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000110e98a9d _pthread_wqthread + 729
    28  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000110e963dd start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please post relevant code, such as your button event handler.

Comment: Can you please post code relating to your button and your segue? You probably need to wrap your segue in a completion handler to make sure all the background code finishes.

Answer (score 0):

The clue here is that the error notes that your code is trying to update the app's UI  from a thread other than the main thread.

> 2015-09-29 18:15:43.867 iOSBudgetManager[2998:66920] Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] **may only
>   be called from the main thread**.'

***After verifying credential I need to navigate to the other view controller, but unfortunately my app getting crashed at this point and given the below error.***

Where ever you are calling the code to transition to your new view controller you need to wrap that call in a dispatch_async call to your main thread - see code below.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
    //View controller code  
    self.presentViewController(yourNewViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

If you need more detail read Apple's [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/)